# Redux-Toolkit createAsyncThunk function doesnt return error

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit's createAsyncThunk function for api request. When turned off network, following function returns action.payload="Network Error" and status = "success". Status should be "error". But it returns success. Any suggestions to fix the problem ? Thanks in advance.

> ```
> import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
> import axios from "axios";
> import { GET_POSTS_API } from "./APIs";
>
> const initialState = { posts: [], status: "idle", error: null };
>
> export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/getPostsStatus", async () => {
>   try {
>     const { data } = await axios.get(GET_POSTS_API);
>     return data;
>   } catch (error) {
>     return error.response ? error.response.data.message : error.message;
>   }
> });
>
> export const postsSlice = createSlice({
>   name: "posts",
>   initialState,
>   reducers: {},
>   extraReducers: {
>     [getPosts.pending]: (state, action) => {
>       state.status = "loading";
>     },
>     [getPosts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
>       state.status = "success";
>       state.posts = action.payload;
>     },
>     [getPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
>       state.status = "error";
>       state.error = action.payload;
>     },
>   },
> });
>
> export default postsSlice.reducer;
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `return` a value, you are telling `createAsyncThunk` that this is a successfully `fulfilled` request, and the returned value becomes `action.payload`.

If you skip catching errors entirely and just let the `axios.get()` call throw and reject the promise itself, it will correctly dispatch a `rejected` action.

If you want the result of the thunk to be considered `rejected`, but you want to customize what the contents of the action are, you need to use the `rejectWithValue()` util as shown in in our docs:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors

Comment: thank you very much, I already fixed with rejectWithValue()  One more question: How to use the string parameter inside createAsyncThunk function, For the above example, I only called [getPosts.fulfilled] and it worked, so why I have to define this string like this "post/getPostStatus" ?

Comment: `createAsyncThunk` uses that to create the action types for all three generated actions, so it'll have `'post/getPostStatus/fulfilled'`, etc. When you use the `getPosts.fulfilled` action creator as a computed object key, it implicitly calls `getPosts.fulfilled.toString()`, and that returns the action type string. However, we now recommend [using the "builder callback" syntax for `extraReducers`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation) instead of an object.

Comment: Just an extra info, error message from rejected promise will be availble in `action.error.message`

Answer (score 0):

To print the error, do the following:

```js
[getPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
  console.log(action.error)
},
```